# breaking space in my citation

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am using `apacite` package to cite the references in my thesis. I realized that one Diploma thesis is cited with space. Such this:

References:

Author names (year). titel. Diploma `thes-is`.

I really do not know why I got this. It should be cited as `thesis`.

I also (if this information may is good to be known) I use this:

```
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
 \renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}
```

Here is the bibtex:

```
@mastersthesis{dissmann2010,
  title={Statistical inference for regular vines and application},
  author={J. Dißmann},
  journal={Diploma thesis, Technische Universitat Miinchen},
  year={2010}
}
```

any help, please?

Comment: Please show us the bibtex code for the entry in question.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comment. I add the bibtex.